# How can I assign an integer to 3Bytes of field?

Tags: c#, .net

I have retrieved the Size of my Struct by using size of like below:

```
int len = Marshal.SizeOf(packet);
```

Now the len has a Value of 40. I have to assign this 40 to a 3-byte Field of my Structure.My Strucure looks like below:

```
public struct TCP_CIFS_Packet
        {
           public byte zerobyte;
           public byte[] lengthCIFSPacket;
           public  CIFSPacket cifsPacket;
        }
```

I tried  assigning the values like following:

```
tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket = new byte[3];
tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket[0] = Convert.ToByte(0);
tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket[1] = Convert.ToByte(0);
tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket[2] = Convert.ToByte(40);
```

But this doesn't seem to be the right way. Is there any other Way I can do this?

**Edit @ho1 and @Rune Grimstad:**
After using  `BitConverter.GetBytes` like follwoing:

```
tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket = BitConverter.GetBytes(lengthofPacket);
```

The size of `lengthCIFSPacket`  changes to 4-bytes but I have only 3-bytes of space for  `tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket` as the packet structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        int number = 500000;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[3];
        bytes[0] = (byte)((number & 0xFF) >> 0);
        bytes[1] = (byte)((number & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        bytes[2] = (byte)((number & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
```

or

```
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number); // this will return 4 bytes of course
```

edit: you can also do this

```
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number); 
        tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket = new byte[3];
        tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket[0] = bytes[0];
        tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket[1] = bytes[1];
        tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket[2] = bytes[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `BitConverter.GetBytes`. It'll convert the `int` to an array of bytes. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I have now tried with tcpCIFSPacket.lengthCIFSPacket=BitConverter.GetBytes(40) which is converting  lengthCIFSPacket to 4-bytes but I have only 3-bytes for lengthCIFSPacket.

Comment: @Subhen: Just ignore the 4th byte and only use the 3 first ones. If you run `GetBytes` on `40` the bytes contain `40.0.0.0` so just ignore the 4th one. Obviously this won't work for too big numbers or for negative numbers, but since you've only got 3 bytes to store it in, you'll have to compromise in some way.

Comment: @Subhen: And if you need to convert it back, just create a byte array with 4 bytes in it, populate the 3 first bytes in it with your 3 bytes and set the 4th to 0 and then use `BitConverter.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class to convert an Int32 to an array of bytes using the [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) method.